# Find $n$ evenly-spaced points on circle with radius $r$.

Tags: trigonometry, circles

I have a circle that has a given radius $r$. I want to generate $n$ evenly-spaced points along this circle, something like [this diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCCQG.jpg) (with $r=5$ and $n=4$):

Answer (score 3):

Recall that a circle can be defined by $(x, y) = (r \cos(\theta), r \sin(\theta))$.  So just plug in your radius $r$, and $\theta$ values spaced $\frac{2\pi}{n}$ units apart.

Answer (score 0):

If the radius of the circle is $r$ and we need to place $n$ points on the circle then a possible arrangement is the following:
\begin{equation*}
re^{\frac{i2k\pi}{n}} \hspace{1cm} \text{for } k \in \{0,1,2,..,n-1\}
\end{equation*}
Here, the points are written in the exponential form where $re^{i\theta}$ represents the point $(rcos\theta, rsin\theta)$.